# Timestamp Processing Brain Teaser

Tags: matlab, timestamp, intersect

I am processing 1Hz timestamps (variable 'timestamp_1hz') from a logger which doesn't log exactly at the same time every second (the difference varies from 0.984 to 1.094, but sometimes 0.5 or several seconds if the logger burps).  The 1Hz dataset is used to build a 10 minute averaged dataset, and each 10 minute interval must have 600 records.  Because the logger doesn't log exactly at the same time every second, the timestamp slowly drifts through the 1 second mark.  Issues come up when the timestamp cross the 0 mark, as well as the 0.5 mark.

I have tried various ways to pre-process the timestamps.  The timestamps with around 1 second between them should be considered valid.  A few examples include:

```
% simple
% this screws up around half second and full second values    
rawseconds = raw_1hz_new(:,6)+(raw_1hz_new(:,7)./1000);
rawsecondstest = rawseconds;
    rawsecondstest(:,1) = floor(rawseconds(:,1))+ rawseconds(1,1);

% more complicated
% this screws up if there is missing data, then the issue compounds because k+1 timestamp is dependent on k timestamp
rawseconds = raw_1hz_new(:,6)+(raw_1hz_new(:,7)./1000);
 A = diff(rawseconds);
    numcheck = rawseconds(1,1);
    integ = floor(numcheck);
    fract = numcheck-integ;
    if fract>0.5
        rawseconds(1,1) = rawseconds(1,1)-0.5;
    end
 for k=2:length(rawseconds)
        rawsecondstest(k,1) =  rawsecondstest(k-1,1)+round(A(k-1,1)); 
end
```

I would like to pre-process the timestamps then compare it to a contiguous 1Hz timestamp using 'intersect' in order to find the missing, repeating, etc data such as this:

```
 % pull out the time stamp (round to 1hz and convert to serial number)
timestamp_1hz=round((datenum(raw_1hz_new(:,[1:6])))*86400)/86400;

% calculate new start time and end time to find contig time
starttime=min(timestamp_1hz);
endtime=max(timestamp_1hz);

% determine the contig time
contigtime=round([floor(mean([starttime endtime])):1/86400:ceil(mean([starttime endtime]))-1/86400]'*86400)/86400;
% find indices where logger time stamp matches real time and puts
% the indices of a and b
clear Ia Ib Ic Id
[~,Ia,Ib]=intersect(timestamp_1hz,contigtime);
% find indices where there is a value in real time that is not in
% logger time
[~,Ic] = setdiff(contigtime,timestamp_1hz);
% finds the indices that are unique
[~,Id] = unique(timestamp_1hz);
```

You can download 10 days of the raw_1hz_new timestamps [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9EIozHd9086c1BWOXprbnJSNjg/edit?usp=sharing).  Any help or tips would be much appreciated!

Comment: If you're logger can't produce 600 records, don't you think fudging the missing data is a bit disingenuous. If you don't mind fake data than pre-process the data you do have (<600) and use the average value to fill in your fake data.

Comment: I'm not faking it, I'm just bumping around the valid data with roughly 1 second between intervals so that it works with the intersect function.  I'm not interested in filling in holes.

Comment: I can't view the link with the timestamps; it says "Sorry, we are unable to generate a view of the document at this time. Please try again later."

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned it - you have to download the xls file as it is too large for Google docs - the DL link is the top left corner of that screen.  It is 10 days x ~86400 timestamps to play with.  Since the drift is so slow at times, you need many rows to see what I was talking about.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that you can't simply match these stamps up to a list of times, because you could be expecting a set of datapoints at seconds = 1000, 1001, 1002, but if there was an earlier blip you could have entirely legitimate data at 1000.5, 1001.5, 1002.5 instead.

If all you want is a list of valid times/their location in your series, why not just something like (times in seconds):

```
A = diff(times); % difference between times
n = find(abs(A-1)<0.1) % change 0.1 to whatever your tolerance is
times2 = times(n+1);
```

times2 should then be a list of all your timestamps where the previous timestamp was approximately 1 second ago - works on a small set of fake data I constructed, didn't try it on yours. (For future reference: it would be more help to provide a small subset of your data, e.g. just a few minutes worth, that you know contains a blip).

I would then take the list of valid timestamps and split it up into 10 minute sections for averaging, counting how many valid timestamps were obtained in each section.  If it's working, you should end up with no more than 600 - but not much less if the blips are occasional.